# Add onchange event to WC3 AngularJS tutorial

Tags: angularjs

I would like to expand on a WC3 angular tutorial that goes to the database and gets format a resultset to display into a table on the screen. The tutorial is here: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_customers_sql

What I want to add is an input box that allows me to enter starting letters to be used in the sql lookup query in the asp page. So I will pass what's in the textbox to the sql to then refresh the table results with only the words beginning with those characters entered:

Here is my code and I can't figure out how to wire up the input field to refresh the table. $Scope.myWord doesn't work. Can anyone help?

```
<!-- Angular -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
</script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" style="margin: 20px;">

<h4>Add Hangman Word</h4>

<form method='post' action='modify.asp' name='theForm' id='theForm' onsubmit="return vForm();">
<div ng-controller="wordsCtrl">
<input type='hidden' name='addhangmanword' value='1' />
<b>Add word:</b><br />
<input class="form-control" style='width:250px;' ng-model="myWord" name="word" id="word" type="text" /><br />
<input class="btn" style="border: 1px solid black; display: inline;" type='submit' value='Submit' />

<br /><br />
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width: 80%;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="text-align: left;">Word</th>
<th style="text-align: left;">Hint</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="x in names">
<td>{{ x.Word }}</td>
<td>{{ x.Hint }}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>
</form>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('wordsCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
var ajaxURL = "ajax/hangman_word_list.asp";
var strBegin = $scope.myWord;
if (strBegin != "") {
ajaxURL = ajaxURL + "?w=" + strBegin;
}
$http.get(ajaxURL)
.then(function (response) { $scope.names = response.data.records; });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Update portion of the code that fixed the issue:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width: 80%;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="text-align: left;">Word</th>
<th style="text-align: left;">Hint</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="x in names | filter: myWord">
<td>{{ x.Word }}</td>
<td>{{ x.Hint }}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('wordsCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
var ajaxURL = "ajax/hangman_word_list.asp";
$http.get(ajaxURL)
.then(function (response) { $scope.names = response.data.records; });
});

</script>
```

Comment: what exactly not working?... the call of the http?

Comment: The table doesn't refresh when I try to use the input text field as a filter

Comment: I think I figured out the best solution and will post what I did here. It seems I don't even have to keep requerying the database if I simply use the angular filter feature. I'll post the answer here in case anyone else needs this. (See my updated code.)

Comment: it depends. of quntity of data the api response... what about if have tons of data.. isnt the bes filter in the front. you better paginate or do something else.

Comment: im not 100% with the solution below if quantity o data is bigger. else the solution below is nice one. ups delete anwser.

Comment: try ng-table directive. has nice exmaple